# how to get OpenLayer map zoomed in iphone?

Tags: javascript, iphone, openlayers

I have created OpenLayer map application in iphone. so i want to access its events by the functionality of the iphone means i want to drag OpenLayer map by touch events & zoom by iphone zoom gesture event. for calling OpenLayer map i have implemented one html file in web view.It's working properly i get the OpenLayer map & the map touch events also now i want to zoom map like other maps or images are going to be zoomed in iphone.please guide me for implementing zoom functionality in OpenLayer map in iphone..

for calling map & touch events i have use this code in .html file

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>OpenLayers Tutorial - Basic Map Setup</title>
        <script src="http://openlayers.org/api/OpenLayers.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        var map, baseLayer;
            function init(){
                map = new OpenLayers.Map('map');            
                baseLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS("OpenLayers WMS", "http://labs.metacarta.com/wms/vmap0", {layers:"basic"});
                map.addLayer(baseLayer);
                map.setCenter(new OpenLayers.LonLat(0,0),1);             
            }
        function touchHandler(event)
        {
       var touches = event.changedTouches,
       first = touches[0],
       type = "";
     switch(event.type)
       {
         case "touchstart": type = "mousedown"; break;
         case "touchmove":  type="mousemove"; break;
         case "touchend":   type="mouseup"; break;
         default: return;
     }
     var simulatedEvent = document.createEvent("MouseEvent");
        simulatedEvent.initMouseEvent(type, true, true, window, 1,
        first.screenX, first.screenY,
        first.clientX, first.clientY, false,
        false, false, false, 0/*left*/, null);
        first.target.dispatchEvent(simulatedEvent);
        event.preventDefault();
     }
    document.addEventListener("touchstart", touchHandler, true);
     document.addEventListener("touchmove", touchHandler, true);
     document.addEventListener("touchend", touchHandler, true);
     document.addEventListener("touchcancel", touchHandler, true);
        </script>
        <style>
        @media screen
        {
            #map{width: 300px; height:360px; border: 2px solid black;}
        }
        </style>
      </head>
      <body onload="init()">
        <h3>OpenLayers Tutorial - Basic Map Setup</h3>
        <div id="map"></div>
      </body>
    </html>
```

this code is working properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implementing this yourself will be painful. You might want to use version [2.11 RC2](http://openlayers.org/download/OpenLayers-2.11-rc2.zip) or trunk, because then it becomes really simple - all you need to do is add TouchNavigation control, like shown in [this example](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/mobile-navigation.html):

```
function init() {
    map = new OpenLayers.Map({
        div: "map",
        theme: null,
        projection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913"),
        units: "m",
        numZoomLevels: 18,
        maxResolution: 156543.0339,
        maxExtent: new OpenLayers.Bounds(
            -20037508.34, -20037508.34, 20037508.34, 20037508.34
        ),
        controls: [
            new OpenLayers.Control.TouchNavigation({
                dragPanOptions: {
                    enableKinetic: true
                }
            }),
            new OpenLayers.Control.ZoomPanel()
        ],
        layers: [
            new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM("OpenStreetMap", null, {
                transitionEffect: 'resize'
            })
        ]
    });
    map.setCenter(new OpenLayers.LonLat(0, 0), 3);
}
```

Comment: OK i have seen that mobilenavigation.js file & i have also implemented that code but it's not working for me as i said i want zooming functionality like the iPhone already have for zooming image & map in it's API

Comment: What exactly do you mean? In OpenLayers you zoom in the same way as in native applications - pinching with two fingers. How is that different?

Comment: ya exactly i want same that "In OpenLayers you zoom in the same way as in native applications - pinching with two fingers." but your given code is not working for me can you be more specific about that.

Comment: this code is from example that I linked to before. open that link on your iPhone and you'll see that pinch zoom works as it should.

Comment: you all are right but as i said i want to create application in iphone  so i don't want to run this link in my iPhone i want the code(as JavaScript or .html) for zoom map(as way pinch zoom in iphone) your above code is not working.[see this link for touch event.](http://www.liquidfoot.com/2009/11/25/openlayers-and-mobile-devices/)as that way zoom is possible?

Answer (score 0):

The upcoming 2.11 version of OpenLayers will support touch events for panning, zooming…
See : http://dev.openlayers.org/examples/mobile.html

HTH,

Comment: OK i have already seen that example but as i said i want zooming functionality like the iPhone already have for zooming image & map in it's API.